# HTML CSS: Diplaying number divided by total number

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display numbers in circle which is number over total numbers for example 90/100.

Like this:

[image: Percentage Circle]

I tried like this but need small help because Circle is breaking up.

```css
.kanban-circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 8px;

    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;

    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;


 }
```

```html
 <span class="kanban-circle">
      <u>90</u>
      <br></br>
        100
                                          
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, if you like more space between the number and the horizontal line, change the css for .line like { margin: 5px 0; }

```css
.kanban-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.line {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%
}

span {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="kanban-circle">
  <span>90</span>
  <hr class="line" />
  <span>100
</span></div>
```

Comment: @code-maker if you find this solution helpful, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as below. Feel free to adjust it to your need.

```css
.kanban-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 86px;
  height: 86px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #666;
  font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.kanban-circle hr {
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<span class="kanban-circle">
  <span>90</span>
  <hr/>
  <span>100</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `<br>` tag. I don't really know why, but through this tag, the lower number is not seen as part of the circle and the border is not drawn around it.

I experimented a little bit and came to following solution with following code:

[image]

```
    .kanban-circle{
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: coral;
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        padding: 8px;
    
        background: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #666;
        color: #666;
        text-align: center;
    
        font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
    
    
     }
     
        <div class="kanban-circle">
            <div>
              <u>90</u>
              110
            </div>
        </div>
```

I replaced span with div, but the result should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

here the solution with also the comments, if you want to read it.

I make it responsive to the width, just change the width of parent element, and automatically change all the things inside!

---

the first 2 lines of CSS are [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)

```css
 --width: 3rem;
 --color: #666;
```

Change their value, and all the elements will be changed automatically, and be show always good.

> if you want to also be more responsive, you can use some new CSS units in `--width:` like `vw`, `vh`, `%`, etc... this is relative to something (parent elements, or viewport width, etc...) 
> so for responsive layout try to not use (avoid) absolute units like `cm`, `px`, `in`, `pt`. 
>  **details:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

---

in html I used [`<hr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr) instead of `<br>`

```css
#container {
  --width: 3rem;
  --color: #666;
  /* same height, same width */
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--width);
  /* responsive padding that is relative to the container width*/
  padding: calc(var(--width) / 5);
  /* always perfect circle */
  border-radius: var(--width);
  /* centering */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  /* coloring with the same color */
  border: 2px solid var(--color);
  color: var(--color);
  /* font responsive to parent container */
  font-size: calc(var(--width) / 3)
}

#container hr {
  /* responsive width */
  width: 100%;
  /* removing a little bug if we use GRID */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span>97</span>
  <hr>
  <span>100</span>
</div>
```